# Box.com api - getEnterpriseUsers - What form does filterTerm take?

Tags: box-api

In http://opensource.box.com/box-java-sdk/javadoc/com/box/sdk/BoxUser.html#getAllEnterpriseOrExternalUsers(com.box.sdk.BoxAPIConnection,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...) you can specify a filterTerm for box.com get users call.

What format can this filterTerm take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Iterable<com.box.sdk.BoxUser.Info> users = BoxUser.getAllEnterpriseUsers(api, "App");

 Iterable<com.box.sdk.BoxUser.Info> users = BoxUser.getAllEnterpriseUsers(api, "Ken");

 Iterable<com.box.sdk.BoxUser.Info> users = BoxUser.getAllEnterpriseUsers(api, "ken@test.com");
```